# hide some marks of a slider and display the others

Tags: python, plotly-dash

If it possible to keep the marks for 0, 5,20 and hide the marks 10 and  15 in this code :

from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output

```
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Slider(0, 20, 5,
               value=10,
               id='my-slider'
    ),
    html.Div(id='slider-output-container')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('slider-output-container', 'children'),
    Input('my-slider', 'drag_value'))
def update_output(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
```

I would like be able to slag on the value 10 or 15 without viewing the labels.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom marks:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Slider(0, 20,
               step=None,
               marks={0:"0", 5:"5", 20:"20"},
               value=10,
               id='my-slider'
    ),
    html.Div(id='slider-output-container')
])
```